# SQL group by and aggregate function

Tags: oracle

I have a following table structure with sample data (only columns of interest are listed). I want the query to return # of bsp_id's completed by # of up_id's.

```
bsp_id | up_id | status_flag
1256     15      completed
1232     1       completed
1216     15      completed
1216     1       completed
1235     1       completed
```

and the result of the query should be

```
Count(bsp_id) | Count(up_id)
    1                 2
    3                 1
```

Comment: I don't see how you get two rows of output given that input.  There are three distinct `bsp_id` values and two distinct `up_id` values.  Why wouldn't you want a single row of output with 3 and 2 as the values?  How do you determine that you want two rows of output and not more or less?

Comment: There are 4 distinct bsp_id's. bsp_id 1216 is completed by 2 users (up_id). The other 3 bsp_id's are completed by only 1 user. Its little tricky, I need the count on both bsp_id and up_id. This is how I'm reading the result "1 bsp_id is completed by 2 users and 3 bsp_id's are completed by 1 user".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a nested query. Something like this should work:

The internal query:

```
select bsd_id, count(*) as c from mitable
where status_flag='completed' group by bsd_id
```

Results:

1256, 1

1232, 1

1216, 2

1235, 1

The complete query:

```
select count(*), t.c from
(select bsd_id, count(*) as c from mitable
where status_flag='completed' group by bsd_id) t
group by t.c
```

Results:

1, 2

3, 1

Comment: Thanks Martin!! Worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant the following,

```
Count(bsp_id) | Count(up_id)
    2                 1
    3                 1
```

then the query should be:

```
select count(bsp_id), count(up_id) // count(up_id) will always be 1
from tbl
where status_flag = 'completed'
group by up_id
```

Comment: Your solution is giving the 2nd row correctly. The tricky part is I need the count on both bsp_id and up_id.